# Hoisting inside function having same variable name

Tags: javascript

So I thought I understood hoisting in JavaScript until I saw something like this:

```
function hoist(a) {
    console.log(a);
    var a = 10;
}

hoist(5);
```

The code above outputs `5`, not `undefined`!
As per my understanding, the function looks like this to the interpreter:

```
function hoist(a) {
    var a;  // This should overshadow the parameter 'a' and 'undefined' should be assigned to it
    console.log(a);  // so this should print undefined
    a = 10;  // now a is assigned 10
}
```

So what's happening here?

Comment: You're ignoring the passed in parameter when doing your interpreter analysis. I have seen exact examples of the code you're posting except that they pass through empty parameters. This is just a regular function call that console logs the parameter. Why would it be undefined when you're passing through a value?

Comment: "*[If you re-declare a JavaScript variable, it will not lose its value.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would be right if the var was called `b`, but the var `a` already exists. redeclaring a javascript variable that already exists doesn't do anything. It will not change the value to undefined. Try it.

```js
function hoist(a) {
    var a; // no op, does not change a to  undefined.
    console.log(a);
    a = 10;
}

hoist(18);
```

Answer (score 2):

This falls back in the section [Only declarations are hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting#Only_declarations_are_hoisted) in the MDN (to link some documentation, at least).

The second example given there is the exact one you're looking for:

```js
num = 6;
console.log(num); // returns 6
var num; // or, really, var num = whatever.
```

To just recall what is said:

> If you declare the variable **after it is used, but initialize it beforehand, it will return the value**.

Answer (score 1):

Hoisting a variable means that the variable name is known to the compiler from the beginning of the block. It does not re-introduce, overwrite, clear or reset the variable **if it already exists**.

Until something is assigned, the value of that variable is `undefined`, but hoisting itself does nothing to the *value* of the variable.

It so happens that a function parameter is **also** a way of declaring a variable, like an invisible `var` statement, followed by an assignment that happens as the function gets called, before any of the actual function body executes.

Answer (score 0):

Hoisting is still working as we expect, as we can see that the following snippet also outputs 5:

```
function hoist(a) {
  var a;
  console.log(a);
  a = 10;
}

hoist(5);
```

What we really have here is a function parameter, a, being redeclared inside the function where its value has already been initialized to 5.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct that hoisting would work this way inside of that function.

In this particular example we pass an argument/parameter to our function and it changes how it will be interpreted. Just take a look:

```
function hoist(a) { // here's our 'a' parameter gets replaced by '5' that we passed while execution of this function
    var a;  // with no new value it does nothing
    console.log(a);  // so this will print 5 that we passed to this function
    a = 10;  // now a is assigned 10 and next console.log() would show a new value of 'a' variable
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Hoisting has to do with calling a function before it is declared, as javascript will push the function declarations to the top. The parameter `a` and the variable `a` don't related to hoisting in this case.

Comment: your answer is wrong my friend. variables are hoisted just like functions. (i didn't downvote btw)